# Value of type 'CollectionViewCell' has no member 'imageView'

Tags: xcode, swift

My build fails due to the following two errors

1. Value of type ExploreCollectionViewCell has no member 'imageView'
2. Value of type ExploreCollectionViewCell has no member 'titleLabel'

I can't figure out what change is causing the failure or how to fix it without redoing the whole project.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cellApt = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellApt", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionViewCell

    cellApt.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
    cellApt.titleLabel?.text = self.condoCells[indexPath.row]
    cellApt.setNeedsLayout()

    return cellApt
}
```

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c1Wy.png)

Comment: In the class of ExploreCollectionViewCell, did you add properties for imageView and titleLabel?

Comment: I have not. what properties would i need to add?

Comment: I just added an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExploreCollectionViewCell should have properties like the codes below:

```
class ExploreCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

`let cellApt = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellApt", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionViewCell`

With:

`let cellApt: ExploreCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellApt", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionViewCell`

Comment: sorry this did not work unfortunately. thanks for your time and effort